# How do I eliminate 3 lines of repetitive code?

Tags: php

The three lines repeat themselves twice. How could this be done better?

```html
$selectedComponentsNewTmp = $this->getNewSelectedComponents();
$selectedComponentsNew = [];
foreach ($selectedComponentsNewTmp as $component) {
    $selectedComponentsNew[$component['componentGroup']['Count_0']]['name'] = $component['componentGroup']['name'];
    $selectedComponentsNew[$component['componentGroup']['Count_0']]['value'] = $component['coverage']['value'] ?? '';
    $selectedComponentsNew[$component['componentGroup']['Count_0']]['txt'] = $component['coverage']['txt'] ?? '';
}

$selectedComponentsOldTmp = $this->getOldSelectedComponents();
$selectedComponentsOld = [];
foreach ($selectedComponentsOldTmp as $component) {
    $selectedComponentsOld[$component['componentGroup']['Count_0']]['name'] = $component['componentGroup']['name'];
    $selectedComponentsOld[$component['componentGroup']['Count_0']]['value'] = $component['coverage']['value'] ?? '';
    $selectedComponentsOld[$component['componentGroup']['Count_0']]['txt'] = $component['coverage']['txt'] ?? '';
}
```

Comment: There are various things you could do, but it depends on what you do with the results later. Frankly, although it looks a bit ungainly, for three lines of code it's not worth the trouble. Move on to something more useful.

Comment: Your question is not suitable for SO - see [ask] and take the [tour]. You could possibly ask on [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @berend this question is not off-topic because it is asking for review.  I do encourage reviews to be asked for on CodeReview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create and use a `function`:

## function

```
function myFunction($selectedComponentsNew, $component) {
    $selectedComponentsNew[$component['componentGroup']['Count_0']]['name'] = $component['componentGroup']['name'];
    $selectedComponentsNew[$component['componentGroup']['Count_0']]['value'] = $component['coverage']['value'] ?? '';
    $selectedComponentsNew[$component['componentGroup']['Count_0']]['txt'] = $component['coverage']['txt'] ?? '';
}
```

## usage

```
$selectedComponentsNewTmp = $this->getNewSelectedComponents();
$selectedComponentsNew = [];
foreach ($selectedComponentsNewTmp as $component) {
    myFunction($selectedComponentsNew, $component);
}

$selectedComponentsOldTmp = $this->getOldSelectedComponents();
$selectedComponentsOld = [];
foreach ($selectedComponentsOldTmp as $component) {
    myFunction($selectedComponentsOld, $component);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could perhaps use an array to specify the final value used in each line and iterate that array within the outer loop.

```
$args=['name','value','txt'];
$new=$old=[];


foreach( $this->getNewSelectedComponents() as $component) {
    foreach( $args as $arg ) $new[$component['componentGroup']['Count_0']][$arg] = $component['componentGroup'][$arg] ?? '';
}
foreach( $this->getOldSelectedComponents() as $component ) {
    foreach( $args as $arg ) $old[$component['componentGroup']['Count_0']][$arg] = $component['componentGroup'][$arg] ?? '';
}
```